# Unable to deploy contract that uses Oraclize. Out of gas

Tags: solidity, oracles, out-of-gas

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract that uses Oraclize on the Ropsten TestNet using truffle. It seems that deploy the Oraclize api contract (imported by my contract) it's too costly and causes the deploy to fail with the error "the contract code couldn't be stored please check your gas amount". If i increase the gas limit i get the error "Error: Exceeds block gas limit".

What can i do? There is a way to deploy only my contract without the oraclize contract?

Thank you in advance

Comment: At least for me, this error is usually due to errors in code and nothing to do with gas. Maybe you can post your code and state exactly where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

**First solution** : try to set gas limit at 4700000 witha gas price of 40 or more.

**second solution** (depends on your contract model) :

Deploy the oracle contract separately 
then create a new instance in your contract to interact with it as follow
let's assume you want to use : https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/DieselPrice.sol

in your contract

```
contract Mycontract{
Fuelprice o;
constructor(address Oracleaddress_){
o=Fuelprice(Oracleaddress_);
}

function getfuelPriceUSD() public view returns (uint){
      return o.fuelPriceUSD();

    }
}
```

of course you need to define in your codefile an abstract representation of the called contract. using this example you can fed the oracle address to your contract when you deploy it (if you're using truffle you can do it using deployment file)